# Horizontal Scrolling Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to show tab one by one if i click next or previous button from this case

[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyberzilla/sw85uasd/1/)

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs list" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tab4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tab5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tab6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tab7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tab8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tab17</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: late for the party, but nevermind. Is it solved already? if not then do reply I have a solution for it. but needs clarification about tabs do they have fixed width? or according to text etc?

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
});
```

to you JavaScript. And then, add the HTML for tabs content.

Comment: i am sorry for my mistake, if i click next button, that show the tab until the "LAST TAB", i want to show the bootstrap tab like firefox tab, one by one