# Scrollable bootstrap tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get scrollable tabs working like [this](http://www.bootply.com/l2ChB4vYmC), however I'm having problems if the amount of tabs go over what would be two pages worth of tabs - the left/right arrows scroll to the end of the direction you click, [example here](http://www.bootply.com/F3zJER60ur).

What steps do I take to stop this happening?

I've checked related questions (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720142/horizontal-scrolling-bootstrap-tabs) which is the same question), but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to require some tweaking, but it's a step in the direction you're looking to go:

http://www.bootply.com/QvjUcSP0ap

Comment: Thank you! Perfect solution.